# With the Job Report Sender can multiple reports be sent from the same job, e.g. instanaceId=1, instancesId=2, instanceId= 4

Tags: reports, scheduled-job

We have a bunch of reports we want send to different people once a week.  The generic description of the the Report Sender sounds like we only need a new different Report Sender job if the frequency is different and that it can sent multiple reports.

"Report sender (Weekly)
Generates and sends out reports via email
API Entity: Job
API Action: mail_report"

So do we just put each instanceId for each report on a new line in the parameters? What if we have other parameters for each report?  Is it smart enough to notice a new instanceId new set of parameters?  Or...?

Or do we need a separate job for each individual report and the generic description is misleading?

Maybe this is somewhere in the documentation that I did't find.  There is a stackexchange that sounds like you need a different Report Sender for each report (instanceId) but it's old and it's not clear what they did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create a Schedule job for each report separately.

Comment: I'll see if I can get the official documentation updated.  It's quite misleading have the description say reports, when it really just report and the job name should be specific to the report not something like weekly.